# How can I make it easier for users to retrieve WiX installation log files?

Tags: logging, wix, windows-installer

Whenever the installation of our product fails, the user has the possibility to click on the FailureLogFileLink link in our theme file. But this log file contains only the log for the bundle, not each individual MSI. We therefore have to guide the customer in order to retrieve the installation log files for us, and that can be quite challenging.

What I would like to do instead, is one of the following things:

1. Log all data (from bundle and MSI's) to same file ...
2. ... or present links to all log files on the failure page ...
3. ... or present a button on the failure page, that via a custom action zips all log files and places it on the users desktop.

Will any of my ideas work? If so, how do I go on about it? I have tried to find ideas and solutions but I've found nothing. Or are there better solutions not mentioned here?

Our installation consists of one bundle with three MSI packages, and we're using WiX 3.10.